# Canvas Blur background

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, blur

I'm a newbie regarding canvas and I've searched and tried alot, but never accomplished to find the right  solution to use this one: http://www.quasimondo.com/BoxBlurForCanvas/FastBlurDemo.html

I want to use it with a image for a fixed background, so I can put the same non-blurred image on top, while having a changeable page, that changes design when exchanging the image.

I know I'm able to use CSS3 Filters for this but it doesnt work on Firefox and the performance of such a blurred big image is terrible...

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you're asking..Do you need help with coding or designing?  Please explain further  :)

Comment: I need help with coding. How to use this script. I've tried but dont know how... :l

Answer (score 1):

*"I know I'm able to use CSS3 Filters for this but it doesnt work on Firefox ..."*

Firefox can do CSS blurring:

First, include an SVG file containing the desired blur in the web page

```
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <filter id="gaussian">
        <feGaussianBlur id="myBlur" stdDeviation="5" />
    </filter>
</svg>
```

Next, get a reference to the canvas element in the normal way, eg:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
```

... and apply the filter to it:

```
canvas.style.webkitFilter = 'url(#gaussian)';
canvas.style.filter = 'url(#gaussian)';
```

To change the blur value, you need a handle to the gaussian blur element itself:

```
var blurFilter = document.getElementById('myBlur');
```

Use the setStdDeviation(stdDeviationX, stdDeviationY) method to change the blur. Both arguments are numbers, not strings:

```
blurFilter.setStdDeviation(5, 5);
```

(Seems to work OK in latest versions of Firefox and Chrome - though Chrome doesn't like it when the blur values are set to 0 ...)

Comment: Thanks! That was very comprehensive :) I did a jquery version as a shortterm "hack" until CSS3 filters have a proper performance. It seems really bad on bigger images in all major (and new) browsers!